# JSDoc - how to document function's static variable

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How do I properly JSDoc the function below?

```
function foo() {
  foo.counter = 1 + (foo.counter || 0)
}
```

Currently TS type checking (in vscode, with checkJs=true) complains:
`Property 'counter' does not exist on type '() => void'`

Comment: [How to declare a Static Variable inside a function in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35053459)

Answer (score 0):

You can document static members with JSDoc. I would use a [namepath](https://jsdoc.app/about-namepaths.html) for this and so an extra block:

```
function foo() {
}

/**
 * My static counter
 * @name foo.counter
 * @type {number}
 */
foo.counter = 0;
```

Now my IDE (VS Code) is able to see it as a property and pull out the documentation:

[image]